# String encoding with Python and MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, utf-8, character-encoding

I need to insert into a MySQL 5.7 database strings with several non-ASCII characters, like `è` or `…` or even other alphabets, using a `Python3` script. I converted all the columns of the interested table in `utf8mb4`.

Connecting with

```
db1 = MySQLdb.connect (
host="host1",
user="user1",
passwd="secret",
db="db1"
)

cursor1 = db1.cursor()
cursor1.execute("USE db1")
```

I can correctly store strings with `è`. Strings with `…` generate instead the following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u2026' in position 1022: ordinal not in range(256)
```

Vice-versa, connecting with

```
db1 = MySQLdb.connect (
host="host1",
user="user1",
passwd="secret",
db="db1"
)

cursor1 = db1.cursor()
cursor1.execute("USE db1")
cur.execute("SET NAMES utf8mb4;")
cur.execute("SET CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;")
cur.execute("SET character_set_connection=utf8mb4;")
```

an error due to `è` is generated:

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xE8 string...' for column 'column1' at row 1")
```

`è` has hex code `E8`.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try setting the encoding to UTF8 while connecting to the DB by doing something like this:

```
db1 = MySQLdb.connect (
host="host1",
user="user1",
passwd="secret",
db="db1"
use_unicode=True, 
charset="utf8"
)
```